# Is infinite inventory possible in multiplayer creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Setting up a new server for my kids. They love creative mode in SMP, so I thought I'd set the server up to use creative mode.

Works fine, flying enabled, however I cannot seem to enable the item selection from SMP creative mode, where you can just pick whatever block you want. Anyone tried setting that up, either vanilla or with a mod?

Comment: Did you use the "/gamemode <name> 1" command to set your users to be in creative mode?

Comment: @Kurley you may want to post that as a answer as that is the solution to his issue.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - fair point. Done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using the `/gamemode <name> 1` command to set your users to be in creative mode. You'll need to do it for each user.  Or you could do it like so: `/gamemode @a 1` if you want all players to be in Creative mode.

Comment: A short remark on my stupidity, i had gamemode=1 in the server options. That is infact enough.
What tricked me was that in SMP the 8 inventory spaces immediately visible initially contain items, whereas in multiplayer they do not.

Comment: @Xorglub - Just as a side note, SMP _is_ multiplayer. SMP = Survival Multiplayer. To refer to singleplayer, use SSP. Also, technically, now that creative mode is introduced, SSP/SMP can't be used to distinguish any Beta game mode, so I guess CSP/CMP should become common usage?

Answer (score 4):

Set the world gamemode settings in `server.PROPERTIES` to 1, that way anyone who spawns is in creative mode.